# Lack of indexing of article in google scholar

Tags: phd

Our two articles have published in two journals
But they do not index in our profile
Titles:
The Design of Novel Kni-10729 Based Compound for Inhibition of
HTLV-1 Protease as Novel Insight for Development of Anti-HTLV Drugs
doi: 10.5812/ijhls.89840; Int J Health Life Sci

The PI3K-Akt/mTOR Signaling Pathway Roles
in Tuberculosis Pathogenesis - The First System
Biology Insight
JSM Clinical Cytology and Pathology
I am waiting for your response
Best regards
Dr. Karbalei

Answer (score 4):

What exactly, do you expect us to do about it? Talk to the journal about whether it is indexed. Or use the manual entry process in google scholar.